# Visual Studio Online Build - web.config connection strings configSource

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

My project **Web.config** has connection strings defined in a separate file using the following construct:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config">
</connectionStrings>
```

This is handy when collaborating on a project or when deploying the project. However, I was unable to get the VSO Build working as it shows me the following error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (4105,
>   5) Could not copy the file
>   "C:\a\1\s\MyProject\ConnectionStrings.config" because it was not
>   found.

Comment: No issue at my side. Can you check the build log to see if ConnectionStrings.config file is been copied to build agent?

Comment: I do not add that file into git. A) password security B) I can have different location of database than my collegue

Comment: Connection string is required during deployment. For password security, you can encrypt the connection strings in the config file. To have different settings to connect different database, you can use web.config transformation.

Comment: I am not sure why would that be required when the connection string is set directly on azure in application settings and is overwritten by azure automatically. If I am not mistaken, they created the configSource option for that reason, so you do not need to commit the connection string (in any form) to your source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection string must be already defined in the web.config and the connection string name must be the same as the connection string name you set in Azure. Then the connection string can be updated by Azure. Refer to the description from Azure:

> Connection strings work in a similar fashion, with a small additional
> requirement.  Remember from earlier that there is a connection string
> called “example-config_db” that has been associated with the website.
> If the website’s web.config file references the same connection string
> in the  configuration section, then Windows Azure
> Web Sites will automatically update the connection string at runtime
> using the value shown in the portal.
>
> However, if Windows Azure Web Sites cannot find a connection string
> with a matching name from the web.config, then the connection string
> entered in the portal will only be available as an environment
> variable (as shown earlier).

And

> Remember though that for Windows Azure Web Sites to override a
> connection string and materialize it in the .NET Framework’s
> connection string configuration collection, the connection string must
> already be defined in the web.config.  For this example website, the
> web.config has been updated as shown below:[image]

For more information, please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

Comment: I see, so I should define those connection strings with a dummy value probably, shouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, just like strings defined in the screenshot and make sure you check in the connection strings to Git.

Comment: Hm, the problem is that if your connectionStrings element contain configSource attribute, then you cannot specify any child elements.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already mark your question answered but I think I should post my solution here for anyone's having same issue.
I create a transformation for the connectionStrings section in other environment with a dummy connectionstring value like this:

```
  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
     <add name="Your_ConnectionString_Name" connectionString="dummy_value" 
               providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

so that I can keep the configSource attribute in my local machine and when I deploy to other environments, I have some dummy connectionstring for Azure to replace.